# Error adding jaeger exporter to RemoteWebDriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, open-telemetry, jaeger, remotewebdriver

When trying to add open telemetry to my Selenium 4 tests

like this

```
        System.setProperty("otel.traces.exporter", "jaeger");
        System.setProperty("otel.exporter.jaeger.endpoint", "http://localhost:14250");
        System.setProperty("JAEGER_SERVICE_NAME", "client");
        System.setProperty("otel.resource.attributes", "service.name=selenium-java-try");
```

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.opentelemetry</groupId>
        <artifactId>opentelemetry-exporter-jaeger</artifactId>
        <version>1.23.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

I get this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/opentelemetry/sdk/logs/SdkLogEmitterProviderBuilder

    at io.opentelemetry.sdk.autoconfigure.AutoConfiguredOpenTelemetrySdkBuilder.<init>(AutoConfiguredOpenTelemetrySdkBuilder.java:69)
```

So I added the these as well:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.opentelemetry</groupId>
    <artifactId>opentelemetry-sdk</artifactId>
    <version>1.23.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.opentelemetry</groupId>
    <artifactId>opentelemetry-sdk-logs</artifactId>
    <version>1.23.1-alpha</version>
</dependency>
```

But still no success..

Who to set-up the dependencies/configuration so that I can start using jaeger-over-otel?

Comment: can you post the full `NoClassDefFoundError` stack trace? that will help to see why `AutoConfiguredOpenTelemetrySdkBuilder` is being referenced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to work around this by setting [enableTracing](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebDriver.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.net.URL,org.openqa.selenium.Capabilities,boolean)) to false when creating the `RemoteWebDriver`:

```
webDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(remoteAddress, capabilities, false);
```

Although I'm using `opentelemetry-sdk:1.22.0`, `selenium-remote-driver` (4.1.4) is pulling in an earlier version (1.13.x) of `opentelemetry-sdk-extension-autoconfigure`.

`AutoConfiguredOpenTelemetrySdkBuilder` (in `opentelemetry-sdk-extension-autoconfigure`) references `SdkLogEmitterProviderBuilder` but that class was renamed in [OpenTelemetry 1.19.0](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java/releases/tag/v1.19.0) so it is not found.

There is an [issue](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/10251) against Selenium describing the problem, which [suggests](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/10251#issuecomment-1019095873) `selenium-remote-driver` is incorrectly depending on the sdk instead of just the api. However, the issue has been closed and the most recent version (currently 4.9.0) still [depends on the sdk](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-remote-driver/4.9.0/selenium-remote-driver-4.9.0.pom).

Picking a recent enough version of `selenium-remote-driver` to align its version of `opentelemetry-sdk` with the one in your project might be good enough but feels a bit brittle.

Comment: Thanks. It sounds brittle indeed, but I'll give it a try :)

Comment: selenium-remote-driver 4.8.1 uses opentelemetry 1.22.0, and 4.8.2 use 1.24.0, so no exact match for your version of opentelemetry but you could try one of those. Good luck and let me know if it works!

Comment: I upgraded to selenium 4.8.3 and it started working!